# how to add table with nested values

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to display terms attribute using thymeleaf. I tried like

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="term: ${contractMap.contractTerms}">
        <td><table>
            <tr th:each="termRow: ${term.rows}">
                  <td><table>
                  <tr th:each="atr: ${termRow.attributes}">
                         <td th:text="${atr.value}"></td>
                  </tr ></table>
                  </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: what is the result of this?

Comment: It is not allowed to save using this sytax into editor. I changed format and used <div> syntax that is working fine.